# Detect button long press on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I would like to start a method from my Service with pressing a physical button (home, back, menu ...)
If the user **long presses** one of those buttons, the service should call a method. How can I implement a broadcast receiver or a listener for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service can't access the UI thread. One thing that you could do is have the activity register the onlongclick listener and then broadcast an intent to the service using a broadcast receiver or the onStart(Intent intent) of the service.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can customize the long press of the home button - reference enhancement request: http://goo.gl/fWbYt

You can however customize the long press of some other hard buttons as mentioned here: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             return true;
         }
     });
     }
    }
```